# vb.net web browser setAttribute Get error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Tags: html, vb.net, setattribute

I'm getting stuck trying to write to a text element in a HTML page with the VB.net web browser.
I can use the `SetAttribute` function for almost all text elements on that web page without any problems. However, one text element is giving me trouble. I have already tried many solutions, but I can't get it to work.

When I try to write to this text element I get an error:

`ewb1.Document.GetElementById("shipment_titleconsignee_address1").SetAttribute("value", "北海道")`

Error: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Other text elements on the same webpage work fine.

Here is the relevant part of the HTML page (sorry it's not well formatted):

I don't understand it well, but it looks like the text input field has some options...

```
<span class="w120" id="consignee_address01" style="position:relative" name="都道府県">
    <input class="" type="text" id="shipment_titleconsignee_address1" maxlength="8" data-key="shipment.consignee_address1" style="width:120px;" value="">
    <img src="./images/icon_down_gray.png" width="18" height="25" id="shipment_title_imgconsignee_address1" style="vertical-align:middle;margin-left: -20px;">
    <div class="title_combo" id="shipment_title_comboconsignee_address1" style="left: 0px; min-width: 120px; height: 125px; max-height: 125px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); position: absolute; border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); cursor: default; overflow: hidden auto; z-index: 1001; display: none;">
    <div class="title_option" id="shipment_title_option" value="北海道" style="padding: 3px 5px; width: 100%; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">Hokkaido</font></font></div>
    <div class="title_option" id="shipment_title_option" value="青森県" style="padding: 3px 5px; width: 100%; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">Aomori Prefecture</font></font></div>
</span>
```

I would appreciate any ideas.
Thank you.

UPADATE:

Now I can see why it is not working. The code above is from the original web page, but in the vb.net web browser, the html source inside the span is all missing, just like that.

```
<span class=w120 id=consignee_address01 style=position:relative name=都道府県></span>
```

This results in an error.

My next question is *why* and *how* can I get the vb.net web browser to load all the content?

Comment: You should specify *when* `ewb1.Document.GetElementById(...)` is called and also check whether this element is inside the same IFrame as the others you can reach.

Comment: Hi, 
Thx for your reply. The `ewb1.Document.GetElementById(...)` is called after the webpage is load completly. 
Actually some other text elements before and after this trouble element are working without problem. Its also not inside a IFrame. 
That make it so strange and i cant find a solution... What is different with this trouble text element to other text elements on the web page is just that there are some "option" to choose on this text element. Looks almost like a combo box on the webpage,but it is a text element...

Comment: Did you try with ewb1.Document.GetElementById("shipment_title_option").SetAttribute("value", "北海道") ?

Comment: Thank you for help. 
The problem is solvend after 5h fight and need only 10 seconds of programming. 
After loading the webpage i had to wait 3 seconds before i make this command. 
Looks like the html code was not complete loaded...

`ewb1.Document.GetElementById("shipment_titleconsignee_address1").SetAttribute("value", "北海道")`

And it worked perfect...